# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: plugins, database, sql

What's my problem with my foreign key reference? This table is not being created?

```
<?php
/*
** Plugin Name: ***
** Plugin URI: ***
** Description: ***
** Author: ***
** Version: ***
*/


class Database_plugin {

static function riverfisher_add_db_tables_activation()
{

      global $wpdb;
      global $wp_users;
      $table_registreringer = $wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer';
      $charset_collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

  if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_registreringer}'" ) != $table_registreringer ) {

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_registreringer 
    (
        reg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        dato date,
        billedeURL VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        fiske_vaegt DECIMAL( 2,1 ) NOT NULL,
        fiske_laengde INT NOT NULL,         
        reg_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_redskabs_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_koen_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_fisk_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_laks_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        reg_cr_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (reg_id),
        FOREIGN KEY  (reg_user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id)      
    ) 
    COLLATE $charset_collate";
echo $wpdb->last_error;  

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
  }; 

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Database_plugin' , 'riverfisher_add_db_tables_activation' ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be with capitalized `FOREIGN KEY (reg_user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(ID)`